# jQuery 3.2.1, Autonumeric Plugin (latest) 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get the autoNumeric jQuery plugin working for USD input formatting, but the file is raising 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export' on line 5450 in the latest version of Chrome on Linux.

I called it after jQuery like so:

```
  <!-- jQuery 3.2.1 from CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- autoNumeric for USD formatting -->
  <script src="js/autoNumeric.js" type=text/javascript></script>
```

So I'm guessing it must be an error in the file? It states that the plugin is compatible with jQuery 1.7.2 or higher on the website, so I'm not sure what the issue is here. Has anybody encountered something like this before?

Comment: Try `type="text/javascript"` (with quotes), at least to eliminate it as the cause.

Comment: Good idea, but that didn't fix it.

Comment: This is bit odd. The error message says " Unexpected token export" indicating that `export` appears somewhere in `autoNumeric.js`. Now, `autoNumeric.js`, in their own words, "provides live as-you-type formatting", indicating that it is intended for use in browsers. But `export` isn't yet implemented in browsers, only in server-side Node.js, where "live as-you-type formatting" ain't going to happen. It's a conundrum.  Hopefully someone can penetrate it.

Comment: Oh wow I must have been trying to use the npm verison of the file instead of the browser version! Well now I just feel silly. I'm surprised I didn't realize that bit about the export keyword before-hand. I ended up just using the jquery.mask plugin by Igor Escobar, which seems to actually work on mobile devices so I'm going to stick with it. Thanks for the help @Roamer!

Answer (score 2):

It fails because you are trying to use the non-compiled version of AutoNumeric, which is written in ES6 as a module, which in turn is still not natively supported by browser (none of them understand `import`/`export` statements).

So, in order to use AutoNumeric in the browser (ie. https://github.com/autoNumeric/autoNumeric/tree/next#in-the-browser), you need to import the *compiled* version found in the `dist/` folder (ie. `dist/autoNumeric.min.js`), or just use a CDN.

*Note 1: In order to be able to use the latest web technologies, AutoNumeric uses babel + webpack to compile the modules into one single 'drop in the web page and it works' file.*

*Note 2: AutoNumeric dropped the jQuery dependency for some months now, try it! ;)*

Answer (score 1):

As Roamer helped me realize, this was occurring because I tried to use the npm .js file in the browser instead of the intended file. Whoops! I ended up going with Igor Escobar's jquery.mask plugin, as it actually supports mobile devices.

Comment: Aha! The conundrum is solved. We can all sleep easy tonight.

Comment: Just to be clear, AutoNumeric in the `next` branch does support Android Chrome on mobile (as of today). The next `v4` will soon be release with this support.